# Como enviar mensagens rede local no Windows

Tags: windows

Como eu poderia trocar mensagens com outro computador (ambos sistema Windows) em uma rede local, sem intermédio de servidores.

Seria possível utilizando o prompt de comandos?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As versões antigas do Windows usavam o [net send](http://www.cezeo.com/tips-and-tricks/net-send-command/).

Syntax:

```
net send recepient_name text_of_the_message
```

Comando:

```
net send windows2k texto da mensagem
```

Se você estiver usando uma versão acima do Vista, tente o [msg](http://www.cezeo.com/tips-and-tricks/msg-command/).

Syntax:

```
msg {Usuario} /SERVER:{Nome do servidor/PC} /TIME:{segundos} /v /w /? Texto da mensagem

msg {Nome da sessão} /SERVER:{Nome do servidor/PC} /TIME:{segundos} /v /w /? Texto da mensagem

msg {ID da Sessão} /SERVER:{Nome do servidor/PC} /TIME:{segundos} /v /w /? Texto da mensagem

msg @{Nome do arquivo} /SERVER:{Nome do servidor/PC} /TIME:{segundos} /v /w /? Texto da mensagem

msg * /SERVER:{nome do servidor/pc} /TIME:seconds /v /w /? Texto da mensagem
```

Comandos:

```
Enviar mensagem com o "Lanche?" para usuário RON:
msg RON Lanche?

Enviar mensagem para todos os usuários que estão armazenados no arquivo USERS:
msg @users Por favor realize o logout em 10min o servidor entrará em manutenção

Enviar o conteúdo do arquivo message.txt e envia-lo para PAULO:
msg PAULO < message.txt

Enviar mensagem para todos os usuários logados:
msg * Por favor, salve seu trabalho. Servidor entrará em manutenção!
```